# Show / Hide background image of div on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm currently trying to figure out if it is at all possible to show and hide the background image on a div with a hover state.
Here's some code:
HTML

```
<div class="thumb">
    <div class="text">
        Header<br>
        Sub-header<br><br>
        Date
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
    <div class="text">
        Header<br>
        Sub-header<br><br>
        Date
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
    <div class="text">
        Header<br>
        Sub-header<br><br>
        Date
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.thumb {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: silver;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: url("http://www.imageurlhere.com") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.text {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

So essentially I want to alternate between a background image and the background color, so when you hover over the div the background image is show, and on mouseout the background image is hidden and you revert to the background colour (silver).
I found this was do-able via pseudo classes but as this is for a CMS site the images will be changed on the fly, therefore they'll have to be inserted via html:

```
style="background-image: url('insert url here')"
```

Is this at all possible to hide and show the background-image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you against using Javascript (or jQuery)?

If not, I have a solution using the `.hover()` function in jQuery.  You said you didn't want to add new classes for new images.  So I'm proposing you store the urls in the `.thumb` elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="thumb" data-hoverimage="http://placekitten.com/250/400">
    <div class="text">Header
        <br>Sub-header
        <br>
        <br>Date</div>
</div>
<div class="thumb" data-hoverimage="http://placekitten.com/250/300">
    <div class="text">Header
        <br>Sub-header
        <br>
        <br>Date</div>
</div>
<div class="thumb" data-hoverimage="http://placekitten.com/400/250">
    <div class="text">Header
        <br>Sub-header
        <br>
        <br>Date</div>
</div>
```

I stored each thumbnail's url in the `data-hoverimage` attribute (it can be whatever you want).

Then, using jQuery, we can use the hover function.  The first `function` is for when the cursor is over, the second for when the cursor is out.

```
$(".thumb").hover(function(){
    var imgurl = $(this).data("hoverimage");
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + imgurl + ")")
}, function(){
    $(this).css("background-image", "");
});
```

I have a working model here: http://jsfiddle.net/auURQ/

Comment: perfect!! thank you, that's exactly what I was after, cheers for that!

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you cannot use the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover) pseudo-class to make the image appear/disappear when hovered?

For example:

```
div {
    background-image: none;
}


div:hover {
    background-image: url('insert url here');
}
```

Comment: I want to show the background image on hover though, again this is do-able via pseudo class like this above, but the images will be different for every div and more will be added all the time, so I don't want to add a separate class for every div, is there any other way around it?

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.thumb:hover{
   background: url("http://www.imageurlhere.com") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.thumb {
      width: 400px;
      height: 250px;
      background-color: silver;
      font-weight: bold;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
}

.text {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

if you have different image per Div You have two way for this

1)make a share css for them and dedicated css for on hover image

```
#thumb1:hover{
   background: url("http://www.imageurlhere.com") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#thumb2:hover{
   background: url("http://www.imageurlhere.com") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.thumb {
      width: 400px;
      height: 250px;
      background-color: silver;
      font-weight: bold;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
}

.text {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

another  way is use JS or JQuery Lib for set hover Event ,...

Comment: the images will be different for every div though, with more being added all the time via cms, so I don't want to add a pseudo class for every separate div, thus why I was asking it there was another way of doing this, show / hiding the background image on hover?